# What could be the simple way to integrate data table using AngularJS as I am new to AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I would like to implement data table just like data table we use in Bootstrap in AngularJS with all the functionalities like sorting pagination ,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out ngGrid, ngTable, trNgGrid and Smart Table, I have come to the conclusion that Smart Table is by far the best implementation AngularJS-wise and Bootstrap-wise. It is built exactly the same way as you would build your own, naive table using standard angular. On top of that, they have added a few directives that help you do sorting, filtering etc. Their approach also makes it quite simple to extend yourself. The fact that they use the regular html tags for tables and the standard ng-repeat for the rows and standard bootstrap for formatting makes this my clear winner.

Their JS code depends on angular and your html can depend on bootstrap if you want to. The JS code is 4 kb in total and you can even easily pick stuff out of there if you want to reach an even smaller footprint.

Where the other grids will give you claustrophobia in different areas, Smart Table just feels open and to the point.

If you rely heavily on inline editing and other advanced features, you might get up and running quicker with ngTable for instance. However, you are free to add such features quite easily in Smart Table.

Don't miss Smart Table!!!

I have no relation to Smart Table, except from using it myself.